# CSS :how to give clickable text something like OSX dock zoom on hover?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angularJS app, and I'm creating a table that will show some data from a picked day.

I've got a div above the table, listing the 7 days in a week:

```
<div class="DaySelectionRow">
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Monday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Tuesday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Wednesday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Thursday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Friday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Saturday</span></div>
        <div id="test3"><span class="pointer">Sunday</span></div>   
    </div>

.DaySelectionRow {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

and depending on what day you click, the table will switch view to show the data for that day.

I would like to know first if there is a way to make something like the OSX dock icons with CSS, so when I hover on one of those divs containing the days, the div gets bigger, and if I click on it, it stay a bit bigger to show that it's the active day.

If this is not possible, or something close to it, like zoom and stay zoomed while active, what's the best way to show an active item with css?

I tried using `ui-sref-active="active"`
as I did with the main menu of the app, but as I don't change states in this case, it doesnt work and the selected day doesn't stay highlighted.

I also tried wrapping my days inside  instead of , then use

```
a:hover, div#test3 active a {
color: #f4ba51;
```

}

but it stays active only on hover, not on click ( I need something graphic to show what current day is selected, so besides the highlight on hover I need to stay highlighted on active, but I dont know how to define the "active" state as it's not a link and not a state, but it will be a ng-show/ng-click that shows a table depending on what did you click)

I'm also using bootstrap, if maybe there is something there that can help me and I don't know it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
.pointer {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.pointer:hover, .pointer:focus {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: that works perfectly! 
One more thing, now how can I make it that once clicked the day, it will stay that big until I click something else?

Comment: you will need some jQuery to add an 'active' class to each day once it has been clicked. See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wkL7kL49/4/